# Joomla 3.0 Hide logo if site on mobile device

Tags: joomla, hide, joomla3.0, graphical-logo

Been tasked with the above title, found the logo, and how to create a custom html module. How should I proceed?

- I cant edit the index of the site directly, unless theres a way to do it in joomla.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the most knowledgeable on front-end design standards, but I'd think some sort of CSS media query would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla 3 is based on Twitter Bootstrap. There are CSS helper classes such as ".hidden-phone" - try adding that to you module CSS (without the dot). If the template was developed by someone else, ask them to tell you what is the exact CSS class you should use.[Check documentation](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive)

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing which template you're using (some templates simply don't load bootstrap) but assuming you've bootstrap loaded, you need to edit the css file in your template directory - templates/your_template/css/your_css_templatename.css

Here, you should use the media queries and find the @media that you would like to change. Bellow the examples. Then, inside the one(s) that you may figure out will suit your needs, set the logo id selector and the attribute to display: none; (example below)

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { 
     #your_logo {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

The options above will work even if bootstrap not loaded. If you have bootstrap loaded and you're able to set the class attribute in the logo, you can use the `.hidden-phone` utility class.